Android: TextEdit.setText(...) does not update screen?
I am developing an application where I have a TextEdit-component into which the user can enter a numerical value. That value represents a monetary value, so - as part of loosing the focus - the application should update the entered string in that field and format it in some standardized format, i.e. it should prefix the value with a specific currency code and format the value to two digits behind the decimal point and group digits in groups of three, etc.
So I wrote a focus-listener for that field and when that is called with argument "hasFocus=false" I am parsing the entered numerical value and reformat it appropriately. My debug output shows that the listener is called and the string that I am using to subsequently call <textview>.setText(<formattedString>); is properly formatted. But for some odd reason that view is not updated on-screen, i.e. the displayed text does not change accordingly.
I have no explanation why Android does not update the visuals accordingly when I do a setText(...) on a visible EditText. Since it didn't work, I tried to call .refreshDrawableState() and .requestLayout() after that .setText(...)-call but that didn't change anything.
Now I am out of wits what's going on here. Any idea anyone, why or how this can happen?
In case that helps: I am using the AppCompat library and while the component is defined as android.widget.TextView when printed to the Log it actually reports as androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText. Could that have an influence or play a role here?

Please share the code that is relevant.

Thanks for reacting but meanwhile I found the reason for the silently intercepted .setText(...)-calls - see below.

I found the reason for my TextEdit not updating: For the interactive editing of the field I had defined two InputFilters (allowing only numerical input) which obviously silently intercepted the setting of the text with prepended currency code. I had not realized that these filters are also applied for .setText(...)-calls and not only for interactive editing, as I had thought.
By removing these filters before the setText-call and putting them back in place afterwards I can now display the field well-formatted while - when editing - one can only enter numerical characters (digits, dot and minus-sign).
